# How can i get an random value out of an array in OCaml

Tags: random, ocaml

I have the function

```
let init_color() : t_color t_array = 
  {len = 7 ; value = [|blue ; red ; green ; yellow ; cyan ; magenta ; grey|]}
```

In OCaml and I'm trying to get a random value(color) of of it with another function. And im kinda struggling to do it, new to coding so il be glad to get some help.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything at all? You can get a random integer with `Random.int`, then just use that to index into the array.

Comment: I am kind of perplex toward your `t_array`. Besides the fact that in OCaml, types should not start with `t_`, it looks like just an `array` with its length recorded. However, it's not that useful considering you can access in constant time to that information with `Array.length`.

Comment: yeah length is already a field in the array's header, O(1) unlike lists.

Answer (score 2):

To get a random number between zero (inclusive) and bound (exclusive), use `Random.int bound`, e.g.,

```
let random_color {len; colors} =
  colors.(Random.int len)
```

or, for the normal builtin `array` type,

```
let random_element elements = 
  elements.(Random.int (Array.length elements))
```

P.S. there is no need to store the size of an array together with the array as it is already stored in the array, so `Array.length` is an O(1) operation.